# Excel 365 Data merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to build an excel sheet that has 2 pages.  The master sheet is where I store Serial numbers.  Sheet 2 is where I update when the part (serial #) is used.

Sheet 1 (Master) Column A, is where I list all the serial #'s.  I want to turn Column A into a drop down list for Sheet 2 Column K (which I know how to do)

On Sheet 2 Column B is where I list which tank my serial # is installed on. Is there any way to make Sheet 1 (master) Column E auto fill the information from Sheet 2 Column B when I select a serial # from the drop down menu on Column K sheet 2?

Comment: Does Sheet 2, Column A list the serial numbers? If not, do the tanks in Sheet 2, Column B correspond to the serial numbers on Sheet 1? By that I mean the serial number in Sheet 1, Column A, Row x is used in the tank listed in Sheet 2, Column B, Row x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. In the master sheet (Sheet1), you can use a lookup function in column E. Since the lookup value, the serial number, is in column K, it is to the right of the value you want to return, column B, so you best use an Index/Match combo, like this, starting in cell E2 on sheet1 (assuming row 1 has labels)

```
=index(Sheet2!$B:$B,match(A2,Sheet2!$K:$K,0))
```

In words: Look at column B in sheet 2 and return the value from the row where column K has the serial number that matches the one in cell A2. Copy that formula down to the row with the last serial number.

If the serial number has not yet been used in Sheet2, you will see the #N/A error on Sheet1. You can suppress that by wrapping the formula in an IFError function, like

```
=Iferror(index(Sheet2!$B:$B,match(A2,Sheet2!$K:$K,0)),"not yet used")
```

Change the text as required or just use an empty string `""`

Comment: Teylyn,  Thanks so much!  This made my day as I just updated my sheet and it is working perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please take the time to mark the answer as described in the [Tour]. That is how you can say Thanks around here.